# If Values from Column A in Sheet 2 doesn't exist in Column A Sheet 1 then add text to that row in sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I'm having a problem while running my vba code. I want vba to search for all the values within column A in Sheet 1 and compare it to values in column A Sheet 2. If that values doesn't exists, i want the VBA to add text to column E in Sheet 1 to that row.

These are my current code, when i run it VBA didn't give any run time error pop up and doesn't give results as well.Thank you in advance

```
Sub CheckValues()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim valueToFind As Variant
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    valueToFind = ws1.Range("A:A").Value
    
    Set searchRange = ws2.Range("A:A")
    
    ' Search for the value in the search range
    Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=valueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
    If foundCell Is Nothing Then
        ws1.Range("E" & foundCell.Row).Value = "Resign"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You could do this with a simple formula: `=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:A,1,FALSE)),"Resign","")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to explicitly iterate through the range of data you want to find:

Note: The above code iterate through the whole column A which is time consuming. Just enough to iterate the used cells in that column.

```
Set valueToFind = ws1.Range("A1:A" & ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    
    Set searchRange = ws2.Range("A:A")
    
    For Each valueToFindItem In valueToFind
        ' Search for the value in the search range
        Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=valueToFindItem, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    
        If foundCell Is Nothing Then
            ws1.Range("E" & ValueToFindItem.Row).Value = "Resign"
        End If
    Next valueToFindItem
```